# JQuery mobile bottom space

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm creating a mobile version of my website and it has a huge space at the bottom of the page. I've tried all that I can to remove it but it doesn't even bulge. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem. Here is the [link](http://www.mobile.siteripe.com)

I've tried stuff like

```
body {
margin-bottom: -25px;}
```

and it still didn't work.

Comment: What device are you testing on? appears to be displaying correctly for me...

Comment: If you are talking about the space below the footer then take a look at fixed position footers: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of experiments, I solved the problem with the lines of CSS below:

```
#footer {
    color:#FFC;
    height:40px;
    position:fixed;
    border-top: solid 1px #FFC;
    padding: 0;
    bottom: 0;      
}

#page {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #FFC;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

I did give the data-role footer an ID called #footer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, fixed position footers are the way to go:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
<a href="#" data-rel="back">OK</a>
</div>
```